# Simple toy example using multiprocessing module crashes computer

Tags: python

Trying the very simple following example causes my computer to grind to a halt, so that I have to restart. Checking task manager shows hundreds of "python.exe" tasks:

```
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=2)
print pool.map(math.sqrt, [1,4,9,16])
```

I am using a dual core cpu (i5 2467m) so I thought the above would be fine.

I tried setting `processes=1`, which causes a slightly different problem: the task never completes but it does not cause my computer to freeze up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem the first time I played around with `multiprocessing`.  Wrap the pool generation code in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

```
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    print pool.map(math.sqrt, [1,4,9,16])
```

What's happening is that when the subprocess is created, your module is being unpickled and rerunning the pool generation code in an infinite recursion.  With the `if` block, the spawning code will only run in the parent instance of the module.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it perfectly (I am using win 7).

Comment: Right -- This is probably the solution because windows doesn't have `fork`.  Nice catch.  Under `unix`, this uses `fork`, so it presumably takes a different code path (which is why it worked for me on OS-X)